# Confuddled with learning C++ / UE4 . Why can't I access this AActors properties?

Tags: c++, unreal-4

Hello all I decided to punish myself further by now adding C++ to my list of things i know a little bit about.

Some of it looks familiar having dealt with C# quite a bit, but i am getting caught out on many occasions.

Here  I am trying to open a door when the Actor enters a trigger in the level.

```
void UOpenDoor::Open_Door()
{
// Find the owning actor:
AActor* Owner = GetOwner();

// Create a rotator:
FString oldAngle = "old angle = " + Owner->GetActorRotation().Roll.ToString();
UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT(oldAngle));
FRotator NewRotation = FRotator(0.0f, Owner->GetActorRotation().Roll + OpenAngle, 0.0f);

// Set the door rotation:
Owner->SetActorRotation(NewRotation);
}
```

[image]

This is likely a very obvious and silly error to anyone with any experience writing in C++. But heres my questions:

Why is the Owner underlined in red? And can anyone help me out with what exactly the pictured error means? (I tried making the FString and FString* pointer , I also tried << instead of + in the string definition. And I also tried without the literal "old angle" string part. ---no dice!)

I've also tried this, now I seem to have accessed the Roll property, but how do I display it in a log output for example?

```
    // Find the owning actor:
AActor* Owner = GetOwner();

// Create a rotator:
int test = (int)Owner->GetActorRotation().Roll;
UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("TEST = " << test.ToString()));
FRotator NewRotation = FRotator(0.0f, Owner->GetActorRotation().Roll + OpenAngle, 0.0f);
```

This code gave me error red-line under UE_LOG saying "expression must have class type"

Comment: Please note that crossposting on StackExchange sites is not allowed. The cross-posted question on SO has been deleted so this one can live, but in general, we close questions here and leave them open on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few things to note in your code. The first thing, however, is that in general [calling `GetActorRotation` on an `AActor` pointer is fine](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AActor/GetActorRotation/index.html).

The red underline in your screenshot is either due to the fact that you're trying to add (`operator+`) a string literal and an `FString` (which isn't supported; see below), or simply because the Visual Studio's Intellisense parser is occasionally confused by the complexity of the macro-and-generated-code-heavy Unreal codebase and malfunctions.

That said:

- In Unreal, you should use `TEXT()` for *string literals*, that is, `"stuff like this in double quotes"`); the macro ensures that the literal will be of the correct type (`TCHAR*`). Don't use `TEXT()` around variables. Your `TEXT(oldAngle)` expression is invalid.

  - To get the underlying `TCHAR*` from an `FString`, dereference it (`*oldString`).
- [`FString` doesn't have any overload for `operator<<`](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/FString/index.html), so you can't use that to concatenate strings. It doesn't overload `operator+` either, in fact, and only supports `operator+=`. To concatenate an `FString` and something else, you must thus do: `FString s(TEXT("Hello,")); s += TEXT(" world!");` or similar.

  - But to build up a string from a bunch of other strings or pieces of data you usually will want to use [`FString::Printf`](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/FString/Printf/1/index.html) or [`FString::Format`](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/Containers/FString/Format/2/index.html).
  - `UE_LOG` itself [takes printf-style format specifiers](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Logs,_Printing_Messages_To_Yourself_During_Runtime) and a variable number of arguments, so you don't need to concatenate strings yourself before passing that string to the macro.
- The elements of a rotator (roll, pitch, yaw) are floats, not integers.

In other words, you probably want to write something like:

```
AActor* Owner = GetOwner();
float Roll = Owner->GetActorRotation().Roll;
UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Roll is %f"), Roll);

FRotator NewRotation(0.0f, Roll + OpenAngle, 0.0f);
...
```

Comment: thanks Josh. I had needlessly confused the issue by incorrectly using the UE_LOG. I had looked at my old tutorial work and seen how to properly do this with %s. Its strange though, I am still running into lots of 'errors' in the IDE but the game compiles and works as expected... I have to got work soon sadly, but am addicted to learning this stuff so hopefully can progress more later and will no doubt be back online with more dumb questions soon enough (apologies in advance lol! :P)